# Variables within function is null

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have the following function:

```
function slideDown() {
    //get the element to slide
    sliding = document.getElementById('slideDiv1');
    //add 1px to the height each time
    sliding.style.height = parseInt(sliding.style.height)+1+'px';
    t = setTimeout(slideDown,30);
    if (sliding.style.height == "401px") {
        clearTimeout(t);
    }
}
```

which is called within this function:

```
function addDiv(nextImageSlide) {
    //finds the src attribute of the image nested in the Li
    elemChild = nextImageSlide.firstChild;
    imageSrc = elemChild.getAttribute('src');
    //loops and creates six divs which will be the slices. adds background property etc
    for (i = 0, j = 0, k = 1; i< = 19; i++, j++, k++) {
        var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
        newDiv.setAttribute('class', 'new-div');
        newDiv.id='slideDiv' + k;
        newDiv.style.height = '1px';
        newDiv.style.background = 'url(' + imageSrc +') scroll no-repeat - '+39.5 * j + 'px 0';
        var a = document.getElementById('content');
        a.appendChild(newDiv);
    }
    slideDown();
}
```

Which is called within another function that defines `nextImageSlide`. It later removes all the divs that it just made.

The idea is for an image gallery. When the user hits the next button, I want slices of the next image to slide down to show the next image. Those slices are then taken away and the new image revealed.

I would like something like this: http://workshop.rs/projects/jqfancytransitions/.

It's for an assignment so we have to write all the code ourself and this is the best way I can think to replicate it. The only problem is that I keep getting an error:

> 'sliding is null. sliding.style.height = parseInt(sliding.style.height)+1+'px';'

No matter what I do I can't get rid of it. The thing is if I define sliding as a totally different id, (for example I made a random little div outside of everything), it working.

This error shows when I try to access the divs, it just made that it throws a hissy fit.
Anyone see any errors in my code?

Comment: Show us your HTML.  `sliding` will be null if there's no object with `id="slideDiv1"`.  Also, you aren't putting `var` in front of a lot of your local variables in your functions which is making them global variables.  That's usually a bad thing to do and can cause other types of errors.  Examples of these are: `sliding`, `elemChild` and `imageSrc`.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong (except the car/var thing Marc B pointed out), but although it shouldn't be causing your error you should declare _all_ of your variables with `var`, otherwise `i, j, k, elemChild, imageSrc, sliding and t` will be global. Also, why set a timeout and then check to see whether to immediately clear it? Why not use the if to decide whether to set it in the first place? Also you don't need `j` at all since it's always the same as `i`.

Comment: ok i figured out why it wasn't working, but thanks for your guys help with the other things. i wasn't putting var in front and it was screwing up some other things, so that's all fixed now, cheers! i'm checking to see whether to clear it because it's animating the height of a div. so it grows it and then when it gets to 401px stops increasing the height. so essentially i want the function to loop until the height reaches 401px.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this is just a typo while pasting into the site here, but:

```
    car a = document.getElementById('content');
    ^---syntax error, which'll kill your entire script - var?
```

Comment: yea sorry about that, it's var on my version, must've got it wrong pasting it here